# crash while setting value in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have got this stack trace:

```
0 LiveTexOpClient 0x000b3d3a testflight_backtrace + 382
1 LiveTexOpClient 0x000b4988 TFSignalHandler + 264
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3c4d0e92 _sigtramp + 42
3 CoreFoundation 0x342edb4f CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1891
4 CoreFoundation 0x342edb4f CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1891
5 CoreFoundation 0x342eea8a CFDictionaryGetValue + 82
6 CoreFoundation 0x343357a6 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource setValue:forKey:] + 38
7 CoreFoundation 0x34335722 _CFXPreferencesSetValue + 134
8 CoreFoundation 0x34335600 CFPreferencesSetAppValue + 40
9 Foundation 0x34c1c906 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 82
10 LiveTexOpClient 0x0006db28 -[LTAuthorizationManager saveLatestSessionTimeStamp] (LTAuthorizationManager.m:390)
11 LiveTexOpClient 0x0002d7aa -[LTAppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:] (LTAppDelegate.m:48)
12 UIKit 0x36209fb4 -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 400
13 UIKit 0x3623ff2a -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 314
14 UIKit 0x361b61e6 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2458
15 UIKit 0x361b56cc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
16 UIKit 0x361b511a _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
17 GraphicsServices 0x37eb85a2 _PurpleEventCallback + 590
18 GraphicsServices 0x37eb81d2 PurpleEventCallback + 34
19 CoreFoundation 0x34382172 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
20 CoreFoundation 0x34382116 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
21 CoreFoundation 0x34380f98 __CFRunLoopRun + 1384
22 CoreFoundation 0x342f3ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
23 CoreFoundation 0x342f3d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
24 GraphicsServices 0x37eb72ea GSEventRunModal + 74
25 UIKit 0x36209300 UIApplicationMain + 1120
26 LiveTexOpClient 0x0002e144 main (main.m:14)
27 LiveTexOpClient 0x0002d28f start + 39
```

code from:

```
-(void)saveLatestSessionTimeStamp
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:self.savedLogin];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

The crash happens only on two devices out of 5.
It was got on two iphone (ios 6.1.3), but didn't get on the another iphone (same ios 6.1.3!).
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Looks like problem isn't in iOS version. Try to output all arguments.

Comment: Also, the good practice for storing key is:
`#define kMyKeyName @"myKeyName"`
and then:
`... forKey: kMyKeyName`

Comment: You might try building without TestFlight -- it's replacing your signal handlers which makes it harder to see what caused the original signal.

Comment: Also, just a guess, but is `self.savedLogin` nil? Cause that would do it.

Comment: userLogin is NIL - excluded case. Would it be due to the code perform on non-main thread (GCD global_queue)?

Comment: fixed. Comrades be careful with keyChain. There is chance to forget that the one doesn't clean keyChains after remove app from device. In my case there was an iphone, that was used during the development. And other two was fresh and new to install app (there is no info in keyChain^ in my case it's userLogin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is self.savedLogin nil?
2. is self.savedLogin a NSString ?

Comment: Let me add to this, is self.savedlogin a property list–compatible object and does it ONLY contain property list–compatible objects?